# how to run gtk app on linux without an x server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

backstory - i need to run an adobe air app, which does some things and takes a screenshot of itself and saves out a JPG, then kills itself. (on linux environment)

I have it successfully running on ubuntu in gnome environment. (on EC2, using NoMachine / NXClient remote windowing app)

But what i need, is to run it automated from a script. on the server. When I try running it from commandline (over ssh), i get the error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

So, my question is, How can this be run automated from a script.

Comment: GTK is reliant on X, you'd probably need to make some tweaks and use [GTKfb](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-framebuffer.html) (i.e. GTK Framebuffer) or find a virtual x framebuffer [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1409090/1584762) for that.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out.

```
Xvfb :1 &
export DISPLAY=:1
./runMyApp &
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
$ xvfb-run ./runMyApp
```

(You'll find the `xvfb-run` utility in the *xvfb* package.)